# Can't get pycharm to display plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I can have matplotlib show plots but not plotly. So far i'm trying to run the code for a graph but it doesn't run. I get a lot of traceback errors when i stop the run maybe thats the problem? Confused because matplotlib shows plot so im not sure maybe bad install?

    `import plotly.express as px
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3],
    theta=['processing cost','mechanical properties','chemical stability',
           'thermal stability', 'device integration']))
    fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
    fig.show()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/warsame/Code Projects/radar.py", line 1, in <module>
    import plotly.express as px
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from plotly import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from plotly.basedatatypes import BaseTraceType as _BaseTraceType
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _plotly_utils.utils import _natural_sort_strings
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _plotly_utils.optional_imports import get_module
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/optional_imports.py", line 8, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import threading
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 818, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
'
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace. I am unable to reproduce. Your code produces a plot when I run it in Pycharm.

Comment: how do i do that, sorry im new.

Comment: this is what i get from traceback after running. running does nothing this is what happens after i stop it.

Comment: You can copy the traceback and paste it into your question, it's the typical way to do it. If you run the file with Pycharm's "Run" feature, the traceback will appear in the "Run" Tool Window, typically at the bottom of the window.

Comment: sorry yes added it now

Comment: Maybe you didn't wait long enough? Loading the first time could be slow.

Comment: also after reinstalling plotly express. it runs fine now but still no plot and also now it opens firefox to a localhost address.